# Maximum update depth with useState to array from map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a component where I am creating a list from an `array` using `map`. For each of the `li` I am using `ref` to get the `getBoundingClientRect().x` and `getBoundingClientRect().y` before adding to a `refs` as an `array` with `useState`.

```
ref={(el: any) => {
  if (!el) return;
  const position = {
    x: el.getBoundingClientRect().x,
    y: el.getBoundingClientRect().y,
  };
  setRefs((prevRefs) => [...prevRefs, position]);
}}
```

The goal is to then `onMouseEnter` pass the `index` of the hovered `li` and do something with the `refs` object for that item in the `array`.

```
const onMouseEnter = (e: number) => {
  console.log(refs[e]);
  // Do something
};
```

However, I am currently getting the error of `Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.`

This error is produced by `setRefs((prevRefs) => [...prevRefs, position]);`

Am I incorrectly adding these objects using `useState`? Also, as seen below in the full code. `onMouseEnter` is running without the mouse entering or hovering the `li`.

Full code below.

```
const MainNav = ({ mainMenu }: Props) => {
  const [refs, setRefs] = useState<any[]>([]);

  const onMouseEnter = (e: number) => {
    console.log(refs[e]);
  };

  return (
    <ul>
      {mainMenu.map((i: any, index: number) => (
        <li
          key={i.id}
          onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter(index) as any}
          ref={(el: any) => {
            if (!el) return;
            const position = {
              x: el.getBoundingClientRect().x,
              y: el.getBoundingClientRect().y,
            };
            setRefs((prevRefs) => [...prevRefs, position]);
          }}
        >
          Text
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

Comment: Regarding to your onMouseEnter event, you're calling it immediately when doing it this way you did. Invoke the function with an arrow function: () => { onMouseEnter(index) } or use bind: onMouseEnter.bind(this, index)

Comment: Thank you @miron. You're correct with that. Interestingly, regarding the `error` if I add the `ref` to a `div` within the `li` everything works as intended. Do you know why that would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is hard to solve if you really depend on setting the state in your render method using ref.

Consider storing the coordinates in a plain variable:

```
// ...
let coords = [];

return (
    <ul>
      {mainMenu.map((i: any, index: number) => (
        <li
          key={i.id}
          onMouseEnter={() => {onMouseEnter(index)}}
          ref={(el: any) => {
            if (!el) return;
            const position = {
              x: el.getBoundingClientRect().x,
              y: el.getBoundingClientRect().y,
            };
            coords = [...coords, position];
          }}
        >
// ...
```

If it's absolutely crucial to store the values in your state, you'll need to check if the value has been stored already or not:

```
// ...

setRefs(prevRefs => {
  if ( 
    prevRefs && 
    prevRefs.findIndex( idx => idx.x === position.x && idx.y === position.y ) < 0 
  ) {
    return [...prevRefs, position];
  }
  return prevRefs;

// ...
```

For the check you could also use your id which you're using for the key on your `<li key={i.id}>` element